# Could not find constructor error with EXM module after upgrade

Tags: exm

I installed EXM 3.5 on Sitecore 8.2 Updated 5, and it was running as supposed to work, I tested the Connection  and I got the Ok message, but the server restarted and it´s no longer working
Sitecore log is giving me this message

Could not find constructor in ReflectionUtil.CreateObject: Sitecore.EDS.Core.Net.Smtp.ChilkatConnectionPool. The constructor parameters may not match or it may be an abstract class. Parameter info: Count: 2. Parameter types: Sitecore.EDS.Core.Net.Smtp.ConnectionPoolSettings, Sitecore.EDS.Core.Net.Smtp.SmtpSettings

-MongoDB is UP and running
-SQL server is running (I was able to connect to Sitecore_EXM and Sitecore_EXM_WEB)
-It´s a standalone instance
File Sitecore.EDS.Providers.CustomSmtp.config is enabled
file Sitecore.EDS.Providers.CustomSMTP.Sync.config is enabled
I´m pointing to Gmail SMTP

Sitecore.EDS.Providers.SparkPost.config.disabled - It´s disabled
Sitecore.EDS.Providers.SparkPost.Sync.config.disabled - It´s disabled

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Sitecore.EDS.Core.Net.Smtp.ChilkatConnectionPool` can be found in `Sitecore.EDS.Core.dll`.

First thing, check if you have that dll in your `bin` directory.

From what I see, in that dll (in `Email Experience Manager 3.5.0 rev. 170810`), `ChilkatConnectionPool` has a constructor which accepts 3 parameters:

```
public ChilkatConnectionPool(ConnectionPoolSettings settings, ISmtpSettings smtpSettings, ILogger logger)
```

And it's configured in `Sitecore.EDS.Providers.CustomSMTP.config` file like that:

```
<connectionPool type="Sitecore.EDS.Core.Net.Smtp.ChilkatConnectionPool, Sitecore.EDS.Core" singleInstance="true">
    <param ref="exm/eds/connectionPoolSettings" />
    <param ref="exm/eds/smtpSettings" />
    <param ref="exmLogger" />
</connectionPool>
```

Check if you have the same dll version as in the EXM package zip file and if the config file is not corrupted.

Comment: The .config was corrupt somehow, i got the original one, put again on the server and it fixed, thanks !